# What is the meaning of 左右着 here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

How would you translate 左右着他们 here? What other phrase could I substitute for 左右着他们 here?

在古代的时候，科学水平还没那么高，人们对自然的认识也是有限的。因此，碰见灾难的时候，就会认为后神灵在左右着他们，所以人们祈求于神灵。

就会认为后神灵在左右着他们，
then they might believe the Gods/spirits are ???

左右着他们
stopping them
punishing them
near them
ruling them
guiding them
around them

Comment: answer at user's fingertips, submit to online dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:左右：(8) [control; dominate; influence; sway]∶支配; 控制
他的行动为她所左右 more examples at iciba:为人所左右 (E at iciba),Linguee:他们将被动 地 为 文 化 所左右,LINE dict.她为形势所左右

Answer (score 3):

佐 means 'assist' ; 佑 means 'protect'. "佐佑"(to assist and protect) is different from "左右" (to make someone go left or right = "to influence")

> 左右 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/332/
>
> [v] influence; master; control

In your sentence, 左右着他们 would mean: "influence them" or "control them"

More example:

左右朝政 (exert influence/control over the government's policy; influence the government)

大企業以財力左右政局 (Large enterprises use financial resources to influence/ control politics)

左右局勢 (exert influence/control over the situation; influence/control the situation)

憑他一人之力是無法左右大局的 (With his power alone, he can’t influence/ control the big picture)

*左右(to influence) might or might not had been evolved from 佐佑(to assist and protect). In any case, its meaning in modern Chinese is completely different from 佐佑*

**左右** = to make go **right** or **left** = to influence; to control

**佐佑**= **佐**助 (to assist) 庇**佑**(protect)